# How to capture a signature from a digitizing tablet?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, signature

How to capture a signature from a digitizing tablet?

I have a device Genius i405X. how I can capture a signature or some stroke made from an application made ​​in C #. NET 4.0 and WPF.

i need make some image from the stroke and save into database

Comment: Have you looked at the InkCanvas control?  It has stylus support built in.  There's a post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234447/saving-wpf-inkcanvas-to-a-jpg-image-is-getting-cropped) that shows an example of saving an InkCanvas to an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF has inkcanvas where user can play with like signature and other painting stuffs. here are some samples

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bsinghal/archive/2007/12/11/wpf-using-the-inkcanvas-control.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16579/Saving-Rebuilding-InkCanvas-Strokes